# How Common are Paraneoplastic Syndromes in Cancer Patients?

Tags: cancer

I recall reading around one in four cancer patients will suffer a paraneoplastic syndrome during the course of their illness but I can't find where I read this and I can't find any reliable sources to back this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incidence of paraneoplastic syndromes appears to be variable and dependent on the kind of cancer. Estimates by Baijens and Manni (2006; [*Eur Arch Otorhinolaryngol* 263: 32–36](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00405-005-0942-1)) are 1% to 7.4% of all cancer patients, however they are citing Gulya (1993; *Laryngoscope* 103: 754–761) and Zuffa et al. (1984; *Neoplasma* 31: 231–236) for the data.

Pelosof and Gerber (2010; [*Mayo Clin Proc* 85: 838–854](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2931619/)) make the particularly salient observation that

> As patients with cancer live longer, and as diagnostic methods
>   improve, this prevalence will likely increase.